# Can't udate freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates

I try to update freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 2d day - and it stucked deadly in a process... I tried everything already:

disabled ip v.6 in /etc/systemctl.conf, changed repository several times, nothing helps, it stucks at some item DL and can hangs days....

[image]

Any ideas?
PS. The setup process stuck same way if I choosen update during installation. The attempt to add new language pack stucks same way.

2. Any other ideas? Obviosly, that's some tcp/ip transport problem! But what it can be if all other internet software works well?! Meanwhile, the Win10's ubuntu layer updates fine and fast in same network! Please, help!
3. Stucked 3d day... 
   [image]
4. Still stucked:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfjD5.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps try [a different mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) ?

Comment: Wondering if there is any proxy access requirement on you current network location?

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/partial/*`  this removes partial downloaded packages.

Comment: I check several mirrors - same behaviour...

Comment: Yes, I'm behind the firewall, it's D-Link DFL-260E, without any strict restrictions - everything works fine - messengers, ftp, http, torrents...

Comment: removing partial downloaded packages doesn't help too...

Comment: can you show `apt-config dump`  please? And `lsb_release  -a`

Comment: sorry I forgot `ps -ef | grep app`

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: [apt-config dump](https://fireras.su/public/apt.dump.txt)

Comment: And it can stuck in this condition day by day:

Comment: Which mirrors have you tried? Only the [Truenetwork mirror](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.truenetwork.ru-archive) seems to be fully working in Russia currently. Have you tried abroad mirrors? Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). And please always [edit] your question to update it, do not post updates as comments. It could bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep app` please.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Been using these commands lately. Without the -get

Comment: Absolutely same stuck... (((